# Pure CSS Carousel work only in mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML and CSS structure that represents a carousel:

```css
.galeria {
  width: 35rem;
  height: 22rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.galeria img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeria">
  <img src="img-1.png" />
  <img src="img-2.png" />
</div>
```

This pure CSS carousel works fine on mobile devices, but doesn't change image when I try to do it with mouse (desktop).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll-snap-type and scroll-snap-align properties are relatively new and may not be supported by all desktop browsers.
Try adding vendor prefixes to the scroll-snap-type and scroll-snap-align properties to ensure compatibility with different browsers. For example, you could add -webkit- prefixes for Safari and other WebKit-based browsers.
If that doesn't work use JavaScript to manually handle scrolling through the images.
Hope this helps!